# Which TeX graphics package is this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, gnuplot, pgfmath

I've been starting at LaTeX for a few months now and I'm learning to plot things
there. I was using Tikz and GNUPlotTex to plot some things, but the end result is
not what I would like it to be.

I was looking for some books and I am very surprised by these plots. And my question
is, does anyone know the program (or LaTeX package) that plot things like this?
[image]

I don't know if this question makes sense HAHA, because I am very new to it.
But if anyone knows and can tell me, I appreciate it

Comment: The hands can be created easily with PSTricks.

Comment: @Qebuqci some gurus here will probably provide a longer answer but the documentclass is tufte-book, graphs are certainly pgfplots, regarding the hands, could be an external image included in the tikzpicture.

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution only for fun purposes. It is stolen from PSTricks' official site.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[rgb]{pstricks}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview} 
\PreviewBorder=12pt 



\definecolor{Weiss}{rgb}{1,0.98,0.98}%  255 250 250
\definecolor{Haut}{rgb}{1,0.894,0.769}% 255 228 196
\definecolor{Auge}{rgb}{0.54,0.27,0.074}% 139 69 19



\def\LinkeFaust{%
\begin{pspicture}(15.5,19)
\begin{psclip}
{\psframe[linestyle=none](0.25,0.25)(16,19.1)}
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Haut,linecolor=black!50,linewidth=0.9pt,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(0.2,7.6)(1.1,8.07)(1.8,8)(3,8.86)
\psbezier(3.4,9.15)(3.7,9.8)(3.7,10.1)
\psbezier(3.7,11.8)(4.8,13.2)(4.8,14)
\psbezier(4.8,14.4)(5.22,15.3)(5.18,17)
\psline(5.3,17.2)(5,18.65) % Fingernagel Daumen
\psbezier(5.05,18.8)(5.25,19)(5.5,19)
\psbezier(6.4,19)(7.35,16.9)(7.35,15.6)
\psbezier(7.35,15)(7.05,13.9)(7.05,13.4)
\psbezier(7.05,13.2)(7.1,12.8)(7.45,12.4) % Ende Daumen
\psbezier(7.7,12.5)(8.7,12.3)(8.9,12.2)
\psbezier(9.1,12.24)(9.7,12.24)(9.9,12.2)
\psbezier(10.1,12.3)(10.5,12.2)(10.8,12.2)
\psbezier(11,12.2)(11,12.3)(11.3,12.2)
\psbezier(11.5,12.22)(13.1,11.68)(13.2,11.57)
\psline(13.2,11.57)(10.2,3.8)
\psbezier(9.3,3.3)(7.8,3.3)(7.4,3.3)
\psbezier(6.8,3.3)(6.3,3.2)(5.2,3.5)
\psbezier(3.2,2.6)(3.2,2.6)(0.2,0.1)
\closepath
}
\end{psclip}
%
% Fingernagel Daumen
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!10,linecolor=black!50,linewidth=0.8pt,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(5.18,17.0)(5.45,17.2)(5.42,17.2)(5.4,17.4)
\psbezier(5.3,18.4)(5.4,18.4)(5,18.65)
\psbezier(4.95,18.0)(4.9,18.0)(5.18,17.0)
\closepath
}
%
% Linien in Handfl\"{a}che und Daumen
{\psset{linewidth=0.8pt,linecolor=black!40}
\psbezier(3,6)(3.1,5.4)(3.25,5)(3.5,4.6)
\psbezier(4.65,3.85)(4.73,3.7)(4.73,3.6)(4.8,3.35)
\psbezier(4.8,4.8)(5.1,4.35)(5.2,4)(5.2,3.5)
\psbezier(2.9,8.4)(3.15,5.7)(4.4,5.2)(4.6,4.4)
\psbezier(3.15,8.5)(3.3,7)(4.1,6)(4.6,5.4)
\psbezier(3.35,8.8)(3.5,7.6)(4.0,7)(4.6,6.6)
\psbezier(4.6,6.1)(4.8,5.85)(4.98,5.7)(5.2,5.6)
\psbezier(5.6,5.4)(9.7,8)(10,9.5)(10,10.1)
\psbezier(10,10.1)(10,10.6)(10,11)(9.5,11.6)
\psbezier(5.7,6.3)(6.2,6.45)(6.4,6.45)(6.8,6.4)
\psbezier(7,7.2)(6.9,6.5)(6.8,6.5)(6.75,6.2)
\psbezier(7.6,9)(7.8,8.2)(7.8,7)(7.5,6.4)
\psbezier(8,12.25)(9.3,11.85)(9.4,11)(9.4,10.4)
\psbezier(10.05,12)(10,11)(10,9.8)(10.05,8.86)
\psbezier(11.18,12)(11,11.2)(11.0,10.5)(11.4,9.8)
\psbezier(7.45,12.4)(7.6,12.2)(7.63,12.05)(7.9,11.9)
\psbezier(5.1,15.44)(5.25,15.44)(5.35,15.32)(5.5,15.32)
\psbezier(5,14.95)(5.3,14.95)(5.3,14.96)(5.54,15.07)
\psbezier(6.7,15.38)(7,15.42)(7,15.4)(7.35,15.6)
}
%
% kleiner Finger
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Haut,linecolor=black!50,linewidth=0.9pt,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(14.0,4.95)(14.2,4.7)(14.18,4.2)(13.8,3.8)
\psbezier(13.2,3.51)(13.0,3.38)(12.0,3.25)
\psbezier(11.8,3.22)(11.7,3.23)(11.5,3.25)
\psbezier(11.3,3.27)(11.0,3.3)(10.75,3.48)
\psbezier(10.53,3.51)(10.38,3.45)(9.75,4.0)
\psbezier(9.65,4.15)(9.65,4.4)(9.8,4.55)
%
\closepath
}
%
% Fingernagel kleiner Finger
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!10,linewidth=0.8pt,linecolor=black!50,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(11.2,4.35)(11.35,4.15)(11.35,4.0)(11.2,3.86)
\psbezier(11.1,3.81)(11,3.76)(10.8,3.78)
\psbezier(10.1,3.84)(10.13,3.9)(10.08,4)
\psbezier(10.05,4.12)(10.05,4.4)(10.18,4.5)
\closepath
}
%
% Linien im kleinen Finger
{\psset{linewidth=0.8pt,linecolor=black!40}
\psbezier(12.1,4.2)(12.2,3.75)(12.2,3.75)(12.0,3.4)
\psbezier(12.35,4.15)(12.4,3.75)(12.4,3.75)(12.25,3.45)
\psbezier(13.7,4.8)(13.8,4.5)(13.8,4.5)(13.7,4.18)
}
%
% Ringfinger
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Haut,linecolor=black!50,linewidth=0.9pt,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(14.65,7.1)(15.0,6.8)(15.18,6.6)(15.18,6.12)
\psbezier(15.18,5.85)(15.2,5.5)(14.2,5.0)
\psbezier(13.0,4.45)(12.8,4.45)(12.4,4.4)
\psbezier(11.6,4.25)(11.6,4.23)(10.86,4.4)
\psbezier(10.4,4.42)(10.0,4.5)(9.85,4.5)
\psbezier(9.2,4.5)(8.87,5.0)(8.87,5.5)
\psbezier(8.87,5.9)(9.3,6.19)(9.8,6.2)
%
\closepath
}
%
% Fingernagel Ringfinger
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!10,linewidth=0.8pt,linecolor=black!50,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(10.73,5)(10.73,4.83)(10.7,4.58)(9.5,4.72)
\psbezier(9.25,5.43)(9.4,5.7)(9.65,5.9)
\psbezier(10.65,5.7)(10.73,5.4)(10.73,5)
\closepath
}
%
% Linien im Ringfinger
{\psset{linewidth=0.8pt,linecolor=black!40}
\psbezier(11.9,5.6)(12.0,5.1)(12.0,5.0)(11.9,4.6)
\psbezier(12.2,5.55)(12.3,5.1)(12.3,5.0)(12.2,4.65)
\psbezier(14.4,6.7)(14.8,6.6)(14.92,6)(14.85,5.8)
}
%
% Mittelfinger
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Haut,linecolor=black!50,linewidth=0.9pt,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(14.4,9.75)(15,9.5)(15.4,9)(15.4,8.2)
\psbezier(15.4,7.95)(15.4,7.7)(14.7,7.02)
\psbezier(14.1,6.5)(12.8,5.95)(12.4,5.95)
\psbezier(12.2,5.95)(11.9,6.02)(10.7,6.02)
\psbezier(10.5,6.02)(10.4,6.03)(10.2,6.02)
\psbezier(9.74,6.01)(9.57,6.37)(9.57,6.7)
\psbezier(9.57,7)(9.75,7.46)(10.3,7.7)
\closepath
}
%
% Fingernagel Mittelfinger
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!10,linewidth=0.8pt,linecolor=black!50,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(11.42,6.5)(11.42,6.02)(11,6.1)(10.7,6.05)
\psbezier(10.2,6.1)(9.95,6.2)(9.95,6.5)
\psbezier(9.95,6.8)(10.15,7.22)(10.45,7.22)
\psbezier(10.36,7.22)(10.85,7.15)(10.98,7.13)
\psbezier(11.04,7.11)(11.1,7.07)(11.25,7.0)
\psbezier(11.3,6.96)(11.42,6.8)(11.42,6.5)
\closepath
}
%
% Linien im Mittelfinger
{\psset{linewidth=0.8pt,linecolor=black!40}
\psbezier(12.6,7.2)(12.9,6.92)(12.85,6.6)(12.8,6.25)
\psbezier(12.9,7.2)(13.1,6.92)(13.15,6.7)(13.1,6.35)
\psbezier(14.6,9.2)(15,8.9)(15.05,8.6)(15.1,8.3)
}
%
% Zeigefinger
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Haut,linestyle=none,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(13.2,11.57)(14.16,11.25)(14.5,10.6)(14.4,9.75)
\psbezier(13.6,9.4)(13.5,8.95)(13,8.6)
\psbezier(12.4,8.1)(11.5,7.73)(10.8,7.73)
\psbezier(10.65,7.73)(10.4,7.7)(10.16,7.64)
\psbezier(9.7,8)(9.78,8.2)(9.78,8.35)
\psbezier(9.78,8.6)(9.9,9)(10.3,9.35)
\psbezier(11.2,10)(11.45,10.0)(11.7,10.4)
\psbezier(12.1,11)(12.6,11.48)(12.9,11.51)
\closepath
}
% Randlinie Zeigefinger
{\psset{linewidth=0.9pt,linecolor=black!50}
\psbezier(13.2,11.57)(14.16,11.25)(14.5,10.6)(14.4,9.75)
\psbezier(14.4,9.75)(13.6,9.4)(13.5,8.95)(13,8.6)
\psbezier(13,8.6)(12.4,8.1)(11.5,7.73)(10.8,7.73)
\psbezier(10.8,7.73)(10.65,7.73)(10.4,7.7)(10.16,7.64)
\psbezier(10.16,7.64)(9.7,8)(9.78,8.2)(9.78,8.35)
\psbezier(9.78,8.35)(9.78,8.6)(9.9,9)(10.3,9.35)
\psbezier(10.3,9.35)(11.2,10)(11.45,10.0)(11.7,10.4)
\psbezier(11.7,10.4)(12.1,11)(12.6,11.48)(12.9,11.51)
}
%
% Fingernagel Zeigefinger
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!10,linewidth=0.8pt,linecolor=black!50,opacity=1]{%
%
\psbezier(11.7,8.45)(11.7,7.85)(10.9,7.75)(10.8,7.75)
\psbezier(10.7,7.75)(10.6,7.74)(10.48,7.72)
\psbezier(10.3,7.99)(10.35,8.1)(10.35,8.2)
\psbezier(10.36,8.77)(10.96,8.88)(11.1,8.88)
\psbezier(11.3,8.88)(11.7,8.7)(11.7,8.45)
\closepath
}

% Linien im Zeigefinger
{\psset{linewidth=0.8pt,linecolor=black!40}
\psbezier(12.2,9.6)(12.48,9.4)(12.5,9.2)(12.6,8.8)
\psbezier(12.5,9.7)(12.65,9.55)(12.7,9.4)(12.8,9.1)
\psbezier(13.6,10.8)(13.9,10.6)(14.02,10.4)(14.04,10)
}
\end{pspicture}
}




\begin{document}
\preview
    \LinkeFaust
\endpreview
\preview
    \psscalebox{-1 1}{\LinkeFaust}
\endpreview
\end{document}
```